# JQuery change image in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I don't think I am doing this the best way possible. Is a better way to do it?

Example: http://www.mudquarters.com (click "in stores")

I want to default to the blue shirt and when you click the swatches they swap the image in the div to the appropriate color. They are somewhat working now, however it defaults to yellow instead of blue and this method requires my css to include `position: "absolute"`  which ruins my background tiling for that section in my responsive layout as it is breaking outside the container.

Is there a way to do this better?

**CSS:**

```
#shirt img {
    position:absolute;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="swatches">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/BTN_Blue.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/BTN_Green.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/BTN_Red.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/BTN_Grey.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img/BTN_Yellow.gif"></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="shirt" class="large-6 columns">
  <img src="img/T_Blue.png">
  <img src="img/T_Green.png">
  <img src="img/T_Red.png">
  <img src="img/T_Grey.png">
  <img src="img/T_Yellow.png">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$('#swatches li').on('mousedown',function(e){
    $('#shirt img').stop().fadeTo(300,0);
    if (e.type=='mousedown') {
        $('#shirt img').eq( $(this).index() ).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: nothing is tilting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixes

**Issue 1:** In order to default to the blue shirt, you can just hide all other images on page load:

```
$('#shirt img').not(':first').fadeOut(0);
```

**Issue 2:** The issue with absolute positioned elements is that they are outside the flow, so parents can't adjust their height. The only fix for this would be to set the height explicitly, taking a note from James Daly's answer you would need something like this (inside the `resize` event to accommodate for your fluid layout):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#shirt').height($('$shirt img:first').height());
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

### New approach

Now if you don't feel like implementing this fixes, you can change your logic to use only one image and update its `src` with the click on the swatches, effectively eliminating both issues since there won't be a need to use absolute position anymore and you could easily set the default image to blue. This new implementation would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="swatches">
  <!--Add the reference to the main img src of each link as a data-attribute-->
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="img/T_Blue.png"><img src="img/BTN_Blue.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="img/T_Green.png"><img src="img/BTN_Green.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="img/T_Red.png"><img src="img/BTN_Red.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="img/T_Grey.png"><img src="img/BTN_Grey.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="img/T_Yellow.png"><img src="img/BTN_Yellow.gif"></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="shirt" class="large-6 columns">
  <img src="img/T_Blue.png"> <!--Set blue as default-->
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $shirtImg = $('#shirt img');
$('#swatches li a').on('mousedown',function(e){
    var src = $(this).data('img-src');    
    if(src != $shirtImg.attr('src')){ //Check if it's not the image we have now
        $shirtImg.stop().fadeTo(150,0.8,function(){
            $(this).attr('src',src).fadeTo(150,1);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @user2701706 glad to hear it, did you decide to implement the fixes or the new approach? also if you think this answer resolved your issue please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it, and don't forget to vote up helpful answers too :)

Comment: I used the new approach you provided as it was the answer I was looking for. It seems to be a more appropriate use of JS to me.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try ... I can't tell for sure though.

To get the blue shirt to display by default, could you not change the order of the images and place the blue shirt last?

```
<div id="shirt" class="large-6 columns">
<img src="img/T_Green.png">
<img src="img/T_Red.png">
<img src="img/T_Grey.png">
<img src="img/T_Yellow.png">  
<img src="img/T_Blue.png">
</div>
```

For the background tiling, try adding `overflow:auto;` to the style for #stores

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.zindex { z-index: 10}
```

edit

try making the parent div as tall as the image

javascript

```
    var $firstImage = $('#shirt img:first-child'); // cache
    var imageHeight = $firstImage.height();
    $firstImage.addClass('zindex');
    var $shirtImage = $('#shirt img')
    $('#shirt').height(imageHeight);
    $('#swatches li').on('mousedown',function(e){
        $shirtImage.removeClass('zindex').stop().fadeTo(300,0);
        if (e.type=='mousedown') {
            $shirtImage.eq( $(this).index() ).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
        }
    });
```

it doesn't look like you are changing the image size at all when screen is small if so you could always wrap that in a function and call it on

```
$(window).resize(function() {
// your code here
})
```